# В opencart 2 прибавить процент к цене

Tags: php, opencart

Как вывести в шаблоне несколько цен, прибавлением процента

- Цена 1 `<?php echo $product['price']; ?>` - базовая
- Цена 2 `<?php echo $product['price']; ?>` - базовая + 10%
- Цена 3 `<?php echo $product['price']; ?>` - базовая + 20%

Comment: ну, умножить цену просто...  `$product['price'] * 1.1` = 10%, `$product['price'] * 1.2` = 20%... Или вопрос не в этом?

Answer (score 1):

Если проценты строго установлены на весь магазин хардкодом прописываете в файле представления `product.tpl` (Максим Степанов вам подробно расписал):

```
<?php echo $product['price'] * 1.1 ;?>
// и так далее: price * 1.x = x%
```

Если необходима более гибкая настройка цен, в частности по-товарно, вам стоит обратиться к функционалу opencart В карточке товара (в админке), существует вкладка **`Опции`**. Она позволяет добавлять к товару его варианты с возможностью настройки цены по каждому из них.

Ну а самым правильным в данной ситуации было бы найти либо написать расширение, добавляющее в настройки магазина несколько полей для внесения процентов. И далее, по всем правилам, через контроллеры раздавать уже обработанные данные на файлы представления. В вашем случае в контроллере просчитывались бы несколько цен и выводились на конечной странице. При этом все вычисления оставались бы в контроллере.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<?php echo $product['price'] / 100 * 10 + $product['price']; ?>
<?php echo $product['price'] / 100 * 20 + $product['price']; ?>
```